# simple htaccess redirect

Tags: php, .htaccess

It's a part of my htaccess:

```
RewriteRule ^post/(.*)$ post.php?name=$1
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ cat.php?name=$1
```

The URI will be somthing like this:

```
www.domain.com/category-name/
www.domain.com/post/hello-world
```

as you see, in the end of the first address (category) there is a '/' and on the second there isn't '/', how can I do it too on the second address? if I will do somthing like this:

```
RewriteRule ^post/(.*)/$ post.php?name=$1
```

it won't work because the server 'thinks' that I mean to category address.
hope you understand thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `[L]` modifier on every rule so it stops processing further rules when a rule matched. In this case you can even make the trailing slash optional!

```
RewriteRule ^post/(.*)$ post.php?name=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ cat.php?name=$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `(.*?)` instead of `(.*)`.

Without the question mark, it's "greedy" in that it will match everything up to the final match on the line. With the question mark, it will only match up to the first match on the line.

Answer (score 0):

Make the slash optional (both times):

```
RewriteRule ^post/(.*?)/?$ post.php?name=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ cat.php?name=$1   [L]
```